# Mongo aggregation with unwind operation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to run a Mongo aggregation for following data:

```
 { 
    "name" : "xyz",
    "source" : NumberLong(1),
    "count" : NumberLong(10),
    "catIds" : [
            "dest1",
            "dest2",
            "dest3",
            "dest4"
    ]
 },
 { 
    "name" : "xyz",
    "source" : NumberLong(2),
    "count" : NumberLong(15),
    "catIds" : [
            "dest1",
            "dest2",
            "dest5",
            "dest6"
    ]
 },
 { 
    "name" : "xyz",
    "source" : NumberLong(3),
    "count" : NumberLong(1),
    "catIds" : [
            "dest1",
            "dest2",
            "dest3",
            "dest7"
    ]
 },
 { 
    "name" : "xyz",
    "source" : NumberLong(1),
    "count" : NumberLong(20),
    "catIds" : [
            "dest1",
            "dest2",
            "dest3",
            "dest4"
    ]
 },
 { 
    "name" : "xyz",
    "source" : NumberLong(2),
    "count" : NumberLong(20),
    "catIds" : [
            "dest1",
            "dest2",
            "dest3",
            "dest4"
    ]
}
```

The output should be like this

```
{ 
    "name" : "xyz",
    "source" : NumberLong(1),
    "count" : NumberLong(30),
    "catIds" : [
            "dest1":30,
            "dest2":30,
            "dest3":30,
            "dest4":30
    ]
},
{ 
    "name" : "xyz",
    "source" : NumberLong(2),
    "count" : NumberLong(35),
    "catIds" : [
            "dest1":35,
            "dest2":35,
            "dest3":20,
            "dest4":20,
            "dest5":15,
            "dest6":15
    ]
},
{ 
    "name" : "xyz",
    "source" : NumberLong(3),
    "count" : NumberLong(1),
    "catIds" : [
            "dest1",
            "dest2",
            "dest3",
            "dest7"
    ]
}
```

I am trying this code

```
private Map<String, Set<String>> getDailyCountForAllCat() {
        Cursor results = null;
        DBObject match = null;
        DBObject group = null;
        DBObject group2 = null;
        DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("name", 1);
        fields.put("count", 1);
        fields.put("issource", 1);
        fields.put("catIds", 1);
        fields.put("_id", 0);
        DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", fields);

        DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$catIds");
        DB historyDb = mongoHistory.getDB("db");
        DBCollection coll = historyDb
                .getCollection("coll");

        match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("count",new BasicDBObject("$gte",1))
                .sourceend(
                        "timeStamp", BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$gte", 1463855400l)
                        .add("$lt", 1463941800l).get()));
        System.out.println(match);

        Map<String, Object> dbObjIdMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        dbObjIdMap.put("name", "$name");
        dbObjIdMap.put("issource", "$issource");
        dbObjIdMap.put("catIds", "$catIds");

        DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", new BasicDBObject(
                dbObjIdMap));
        groupFields.put("issourceCount", new BasicDBObject("$sum", "$count"));
        group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);

        Map<String, Object> dbObjIdMap2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        dbObjIdMap2.put("name", "$_id.name");
        dbObjIdMap2.put("issource", "$_id.issource");
        DBObject groupFields2 = new BasicDBObject("_id", new BasicDBObject(
                dbObjIdMap2));
        groupFields2.put(
                "catIds",
                new BasicDBObject("$push", new BasicDBObject("catId",
                        "$_id.catIds").sourceend("catCount",
                        "$issourceCount")));
        groupFields2.put("count", new BasicDBObject("$sum", "$issourceCount"));

        group2 = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields2);

        AggregationOptions aggregationOptions = AggregationOptions.builder()
                .batchSize(1000)
                .outputMode(AggregationOptions.OutputMode.CURSOR)
                .allowDiskUse(true).build();
        results = coll.aggregate(Arrays.asList(match, project,group, unwind,group2),
                aggregationOptions);

        final Iterator<DBObject> iterator = results;

        Iterable<DBObject> iterableResults = new Iterable<DBObject>() {

            @Override
            public Iterator<DBObject> iterator() {
                return iterator;
            }
        };

        Iterator<DBObject> dbi = iterableResults.iterator();
        Map<String,List<sourceCatCount>> nameMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<sourceCatCount>>();
        while (dbi.hasNext()) {
            try {
                DBObject dbo = dbi.next();
                System.out.println(dbo);
                DBObject id = (DBObject) dbo.get("_id");
                String name = id.get("name").toString();

                String issource = id.get("issource").toString();
                Object obj = dbo.get("count");

                BasicDBList catList = null;
                Long countVal = 0l;
                        try {
                            countVal = ((Double) Double.parseDouble(obj.toString()))
                                    .longValue();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            countVal = ((Double) obj).longValue();
                        }
                try {
                    catList = (BasicDBList) (dbo.get("catIds"));
                    for(Object bdb : catList){
                        if(bdb instanceof BasicDBObject){
                            String catVal = "";
                            Long sum = 0l;
                            catVal = ((BasicDBObject) bdb).getString("catId");
                            try {
                                sum = ((Double) Double.parseDouble(((BasicDBObject) bdb).getString("catCount")))
                                        .longValue();

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                sum = Long.parseLong(((BasicDBObject) bdb).getString("catCount"));
                            }
                            List<sourceCatCount> catListClass = null;
                            if (nameMap.containsKey(name)) {
                                catListClass = nameMap.get(name);
                            } else {
                                catListClass = new LinkedList<NewUtil.sourceCatCount>();
                            }
                            sourceCatCount sourceCatCount = new sourceCatCount(Long.parseLong(issource), catVal, countVal,sum);
                            catListClass.add(sourceCatCount);
                            nameMap.put(name, catListClass);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } catch (Exception e1) {

            }
        }

        Long total = 0l;
        for(String key : nameMap.keySet()){
            List<sourceCatCount> catList = nameMap.get(key);
            System.out.println(key+"---------------"+catList.size());
            for(sourceCatCount cl : catList){
                total = total + cl.getCount();
            }
            System.out.println(key+"-----------"+total);
            total = 0l;
        }

        return null;
    }

    class sourceCatCount{
        Long issource;
        String catId;
        Long count;
        Long catCount;

        public sourceCatCount(Long issource,String catId,Long count,Long catCount) {
            this.issource = issource;
            this.catId = catId;
            this.count = count;
            this.catCount = catCount;
        }

        public Long getIssource() {
            return issource;
        }

        public void setIssource(Long issource) {
            this.issource = issource;
        }

        public String getCatId() {
            return catId;
        }

        public void setCatId(String catId) {
            this.catId = catId;
        }

        public Long getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public void setCount(Long count) {
            this.count = count;
        }

        public Long getCatCount() {
            return catCount;
        }

        public void setCatCount(Long catCount) {
            this.catCount = catCount;
        }


    }
```

The above gives me the result where the count field is sum of all count in array field but that should not be the case.  Could you please help me to write an aggregation method with unwind operation to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Can you show us the attempts?

Comment: Your desired output is invalid on the field `catIds`, can you revisit this please and validate the output?